# Html page rendering issue in IE10

Tags: html, asp.net, css, styles, internet-explorer-10

I have a website developed by using jquery and have a dynamic style of coding.

it works fine in IE10 while running from Visual Studio.But after deploying into production server, the entire style has been broken in IE10.

in all other versions of IE(IE11,IE8) and also in chrome,it rendering properly.But have rendering issue in mozilla.

I have tried the below meta tag in each html page head section

and

Can anybody help me for this issue to be get solved?

Thanks in advance.

Page source:

Approver Page

```
<link href="Scripts/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Scripts/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Scripts/css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/script/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper" id="wrap">
        <div id="approver-intro-page" class="ancNav">
            <p>
                Welcome you have logged in as <span id="LoggedInName" class="role">
                </span>
            </p>
            <a href="#" id="btnHome">Home</a> <a href="javascript:SuperAdminTab();" class="btnSuperAdmin"
                style="display: none;">Super Admin</a>
            <input type="image" src="Scripts/images/searchicon.png" class="btnSearch" id="btnSearchpg1" />
            <input type="text" class="txtSearchName" id="txtSearchNamepg1" style="margin-left: 440px"
                maxlength="30" data-watermark="Search by Request Id" />
            <div class="clr">
            </div>
            <h3>
                <span id="Approvername"></span><span class="Welcome">Welcome to Safety
                    Permit App!</span> <span class="Note"></span>
            </h3>
            <h4>
                <span>Request Category</span> <span>Notifications</span>
            </h4>
            <div class="fleft approver-contents-header" id="ApproverPageContent">
            </div>
            <div id="ApproverNotificationDiv">
            </div>
            <div class="clr">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hot-wrk-prmt" id="AppReqPage" style="display: none;">
            <p>
                Welcome you have logged in as <span id="LoggedInName1" class="role">
                </span>
            </p>
            <a href="#" id="ApproverHome" style="text-decoration: none;">Home</a> <a href="javascript:SuperAdminTab();"
                class="btnSuperAdmin">Super Admin</a>
            <input type="image" src="Scripts/images/searchicon.png" class="btnSearch" id="btnSearchpg2" />
            <input type="text" class="txtSearchName" id="txtSearchNamepg2" style="margin-left: 440px"
                maxlength="30" data-watermark="Search by Request Id" />
            <div class="clr">
            </div>
            <label id="PermitName" style="display: none">
            </label>
            <h4 style="margin-top: 42px;">
                <span>Request ID</span> <span class="wid11">Raised by</span> <span class="wid12">Request
                    Date</span> <span class="wid13">Status</span> <span>Action</span>
            </h4>
            <div id="approver-contents-scroll">
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Back" id="backbutton" />
        </div>
        <div class="wrk-details-individual" style="display: none;">
            <div id="ApproverRequestDetails">
            </div>
            <div class="reject-button">
                <span class="fleft">
                    <input type="button" value="Reject" id="btnRejectRequest" /></span> <span class="fleft">
                        <input type="button" value="Approve" id="btnApproveRequest" /></span>
            </div>
            <div class="wrk-details lft" id="Rejectionreason" style='display: none'>
                <label>
                    Reason for Rejection</label>
                <div>
                    <textarea rows="5" cols="5" id="rejecttextarea" class="textarealimit"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="save-button">
                <span class="fleft">
                    <input type="button" value="Save" id="btnSaveRejectionReason" /></span> <span class="fleft">
                        <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="btnCloseRejectionReason" /></span>
            </div>
            <div class="clr">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="permit-cancel" style="display: none">
            <h4>
                Permit Cancellation</h4>
</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could we maybe see some code?

Comment: Use your browser tools to see if the styles are loaded, if the javascript is rendered, what style you expect and what you see...

Comment: The styles working properly in other browsers but not in IE10. Then how to make it work?

Comment: @PraveenVR You need to define the "working properly" and be more specific. Also can be 2-3 or maybe more reasons... Check your browser debug tools to find the reason. Maybe the css is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the below in `head` tag.

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`